# Require.context regex issue

Tags: javascript, regex, require

The require.context function that brings files based on the regex expression.

I want to add to starts with expression to these expressions so fetch that only starts with `1-**.js` files. How can I do that?

```js
 const folders = require.context("@/views", true, /^1-.*\.js$/, "lazy")

// 1-asd.js => true
// 2-asd.js => false
// 1-bsd.js => true
```

The paths that the regex engine receives look like this:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this  .context("@/views", true, /^1-.*\.js$/, "lazy")

Comment: Yeah, only js extension working as I expected. But when it comes to adding a starts with expression, it doesn't work..

Comment: Ok, do you know what the string input looks like? Can you get it somehow? We need more details to be able to help.

Comment: 1-beers.js => this is the filename, that I want to fetch. of course, there are many file names but I want to fetch only includes start with 1-

Comment: That is the filename, but what does the regex engine get as an input?

Comment: Probably you asking to me this input: https://ibb.co/KF23d0F

Comment: As I thought.  You need `/^(?:.*\/)?1-[^\/]*\.js$/`, or `/^.*\/1-[^\/]*\.js$/` if `/` is always there

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Omg, that works like a charm! Thanks! What was the problem, why general solution didn't work?

Comment: @Mert ... *"What was the problem"* ... your regex targets the pure file name only and does not take into account the possible filepath's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input strings that the engine regex gets contain both the folder and file name parts. Thus, to make sure you match `1-` at the start of the file name only, you need to match till the last slash:

```js
/^(?:.*\/)?1-[^\/]*\.js$/
```

Or, if the `/` is always present in the paths, you can shorten the regex to

```js
/^.*\/1-[^\/]*\.js$/
\/1-[^\/]*\.js$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*\/)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `/`
- `1-` - `1-` string
- `[^\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.js$` - `.js` at the end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wHKv9m/1)